# Story where dogs are smarter than humans

Tags: story-identification

While reading Yuval Harari's "*Sapiens*" I remembered a detail from a story, I just can't seem to remember which story.

The detail is that dogs were the dominant species when humans and wolves started hunting together. One thing the wolves got from this was that humans could see farther, since they were standing on two legs.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: What do you mean *["story"](https://media1.giphy.com/media/EYLrxsMg0EaNW/giphy.webp)*?

Answer (score 3):

It could be *"City" by Clifford Simak*.

Per [Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/City-S-F-MASTERWORKS-Clifford-Simak/dp/0575105232/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1530048127&sr=8-1&keywords=city%20clifford%20d%20simak);

> On a far future Earth, mankind's achievements are immense:
>   artificially intelligent robots, genetically uplifted animals,
>   interplanetary travel, genetic modification of the human form itself.
>
> But nothing comes without a cost. Humanity is tired, its vigour all
>   but gone. Society is breaking down into smaller communities,
>   dispersing into the countryside and abandoning the great cities of the
>   world.
>
> As the human race dwindles and declines, which of its great creations
>   will inherit the Earth? And which will claim the stars?

Comment: There are lots of stories about smart dogs in the future. However, the phrase "when humans and wolves started hunting together" suggests to me that the OP's story is set in the prehistoric past.